# How to use testNG @Parameters in @BeforeSuite to read resource file

Tags: java, testng

I am using `testNG` with `Selenium webdriver2.0`.

In my `testNG.xml` I have

```
<suite data-provider-thread-count="2" name="selenium FrontEnd Test" parallel="false" skipfailedinvocationCounts="false" thread-count="2">
  <parameter name="config_file" value="src/test/resources/config.properties/"/>
  <test annotations="JDK" junit="false" name="CarInsurance Sanity Test" skipfailedinvocationCounts="false" verbose="2">
    <parameter name="config-file" value="src/test/resources/config.properties/"/>
    <groups>
      <run>
        <include name="abstract"/>
        <include name="Sanity"/>
      </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
    </classes>
  </test> 
</suite>
```

In java file

```
@BeforeSuite(groups = { "abstract" } )
@Parameters(value = { "config-file" })
public void initFramework(String configfile) throws Exception 
{
    Reporter.log("Invoked init Method \n",true);

    Properties p = new Properties();
    FileInputStream  conf = new FileInputStream(configfile);
    p.load(conf);

    siteurl = p.getProperty("BASEURL");
    browser = p.getProperty("BROWSER");
    browserloc = p.getProperty("BROWSERLOC");

}
```

Getting error as

> AILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeSuite initFramework
>   org.testng.TestNGException: 
>   Parameter 'config-file' is required by @Configuration on method initFramework
>   but has not been marked @Optional or defined in

How to use `@Parameters` for resource file?

Comment: Your testng.xml data is missing in your post..

Comment: Please post the contents of your testng.xml file - it is required to see the context of 'config-file' parameter.

Answer (score 15):

Looks like your `config-file` parameter is not defined at the `<suite>` level. There are several ways to solve this:
1. Make sure the `<parameter>` element is defined within `<suite>` tag but outside of any `<test>`:

```
 <suite name="Suite1" >
   <parameter name="config-file" value="src/test/resources/config.properties/" />
   <test name="Test1" >
      <!-- not here -->
   </test>
 </suite>
```

2. If you want to have the default value for the parameter in the Java code despite the fact it is specified in `testng.xml` or not, you can add `@Optional` annotation to the method parameter:

```
@BeforeSuite
@Parameters( {"config-file"} )
public void initFramework(@Optional("src/test/resources/config.properties/") String configfile) {
    //method implementation here
}
```

**EDIT** (based on posted testng.xml):

Option 1:

```
<suite>
  <parameter name="config-file" value="src/test/resources/config.properties/"/>
  <test >
    <groups>
      <run>
        <include name="abstract"/>
        <include name="Sanity"/>
      </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
      <!--put classes here -->
    </classes>
  </test> 
</suite>
```

Option 2:

```
@BeforeTest
@Parameters( {"config-file"} )
public void initFramework(@Optional("src/test/resources/config.properties/") String configfile) {
    //method implementation here
}
```

In any case, I would recommend not having two parameters with almost identical names, identical values, and different scope.

Comment: <suite data-provider-thread-count="2" name="selenium FrontEnd Test" parallel="false" skipfailedinvocationCounts="false" thread-count="2">
    <parameter name="config_file" value="src/test/resources/config.properties/"/>
      <test annotations="JDK" junit="false" name="CarInsurance Sanity Test" skipfailedinvocationCounts="false" verbose="2">
    <parameter name="config-file" value="src/test/resources/config.properties/"/>
    <groups>
      <run>
        <include name="abstract"/>
        <include name="Sanity"/>
      </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
    </classes>
  </test>

</suite>

Comment: The problem with this xml is that you have two parameters for config: "config_file" on suite level and "config-file" on the test level. I would suggest leaving one on the suite level and naming it accordingly - name in Java file and XML should be the same. If you feel like leaving the one on test level, then change the annotation for initFramework(String) method to @BeforeTest. Additional note, your class definition does not have any classes specified to run. Are you able to execute any tests?

Comment: Awesome. This saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `@Parameter` in `@BeforeSuite`. Suite level parameters are parsed once the suite begins execution and I believe TestNG invokes `@BeforeSuite` even before the suite is processed:

Here is a workaround: add `ITestContext` in method parameters to inject

```
@BeforeSuite(groups = { "abstract" } )
@Parameters({ "configFile" })
public void initFramework(ITestContext context, String configFile) throws Exception {
```