# Getting error as Parameter 'browserType' is required by @Configuration on method setUp

Tags: java, xml, selenium, testng

I am trying to pass browser type as a parameter in my testng xml to my Base Test class.
Below is the XML file sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<test name="SampleTest-nogrid-ff" preserve-order="false">
    <parameter name="browserType" value="ff"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="Test.classes1.SomeTest"/>
    </classes>
</test></suite>
```

And below is my Base test Java class which utilizes the browsertype parameter to instantiate webdriver:

```
@BeforeClass
@Parameters({"browserType"})
public void setUp(String browserType) throws IOException {

        if (browserType.equals("ff")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        } else if (browserType.equals("chrome")) {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\11111\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        } else if (browserType.equals("ie")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\11111\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
            ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
            ieCapabilities.setCapability("ensureCleanSession", true);
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        } else {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\Users\\111111\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla Firefox31\\Firefox.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }
        }
```

On running this , I am getting error as:

Parameter 'browserType' is required by @Configuration on method setUp but has not been marked @Optional or defined

I have ensured that its as per the standard and checked the solutions below:
[How to use testNG @Parameters in @BeforeSuite to read resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651725/how-to-use-testng-parameters-in-beforesuite-to-read-resource-file)

[Parameter 'google' is required by @Configuration on method setUp but has not been marked @Optional or defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735283/parameter-google-is-required-by-configuration-on-method-setup-but-has-not-bee)

Also, I have tried placing the parameter at suite level in testng xml.

But to no benefit. Any help on the question would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Run the test as testng suite, then you will not get the error. Right click on testng.xml and then select run as "TestNG" suite.

Comment: Sir, I would do that but it gives me only option to run as "XSL transformation". Any other options?

Comment: What IDE you are using ? If you are using ecliple, do you have TestNG plug in installed ? If not please do so and try.

Comment: THanks Sandipan, my TESTNG installation had gone corrupt.